# How to disable the microphone beep sound without muting the phone settings?

Tags: java, audio, volume, microphone, siri

I am creating an app for Android devices that allows you to use your microphone like Siri but I am having trouble with the annoying microphone activation and deactivation beep sound.  I can mute the beep sound, however, it mutes my notification and call volume control, as new devices place the notification and call volume as one setting.  Is there a way to disable the beep sound without altering the device sound controls?

---

Here is what I am using:

---

```
@RequiresApi(api = VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void muteBeepSoundOfRecorder() {
        AudioManager amanager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (amanager != null) {
            amanager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
            amanager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
        }
    }
```

---

and on my start command I used a try and catch as the following:

---

```
try {
                ((AudioManager) Objects.requireNonNull(
                        getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE))).setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

---

Nothing seems to work to turn off the beep sound without muting the phone settings.